# SQL Server XML Data - Not Returning Value

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a simple script that is returning data from an XML column.

```
 SELECT 
 CONVERT(XML,[DATA]).value('(/FormSection/FormSection/Form/Breathing/SmokingStatus/node())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') [SMOKING STATUS]
 FROM MYTABLE
```

Which works completely fine when a value has been recorded textually like below and the value non-smoker is returned to the grid:

```
 <SmokingStatus points="null" code="nonSmoker">non smoker</SmokingStatus>
```

However when I find values like false or true like in the xml below, its returning NULL

```
 <RequestCessationYes value="false" />
```

Could anyone point out what I am missing please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `@` symbol prior to the element's name to get values like that:

```
SELECT V.X.value('(RequestCessationYes/@value)[1]','varchar(5)') AS [value]
FROM (VALUES(CAST('<RequestCessationYes value="false" />' AS xml)))V(X);
```